# Laurent series expansion for ODE.

Tags: cv.complex-variables, differential-equations

OK, then I read Frobenius method in mathworld (I learned when I took ODE 2):
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusMethod.html

My question is:
Are there any ODEs where the solution is given by full Laurent series?, i.e its negative indexed coeffecients are not zero starting from some negative integer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every analytic function in a ring has a Laurent expansion. Thus if your differential equation
has a solution analytic in a ring it has a Laurent expansion. See the examples given in other answers.

The difference between a full Laurent
series (I understand that "full" means infinitely many coefficients in both directions) and
a Frobenius series (which is infinite in only one direction) is that you cannot manipulate
with a full Laurent series formally. In particular, you cannot multiply two such series:
the coefficient of the product is a series, rather than a finite sum.

For this reason, the use of full Laurent series is limited.
The advantage of the one-suded series is that you can substitute a formal one-sided series to the differential equation and effectively determine its coefficients (like in Frobenius method). You cannot do this
with a full Laurent series.

Thus a full Laurent series solution (when exists) is usually impossible to find explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Take any two linearly independent  functions analytic in an annulus and you can find a second-order linear DE that has these as a fundamental set of solutions.

Comment: Ok, what I meant is that if I have some nonlinear ode, like:

$$y''+(y')^2+y^3=0$$

How do I know if I need to guess a Laurent series or any other solution?
I mean before imposing initial conditions.


Comment: You might be interested in the Painlevé property (= no mobile essential singularity) http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PainleveProperty.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two related notions for linear ODEs with meromorphic coefficients that have a pole at say $z=0$. The notion of [regular singular point](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Regular_singular_point) (which means that any solution grows no faster at $0$ than $|z|^{-d}$ for some $d$) and the notion of the [Fuchs condition](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fuchsian_equation) (which means that the orders of the poles at $0$ of the meromorphic coefficients satisfy some inequalities). The growth condition implies that the Laurent expansion of any solution necessarily starts at some finite negative order (determined by $d$). According to the second link, these two conditions are equivalent. Unfortunately, I don't have a handy reference for where this is discussed in more detail.

For a non-linear equation, it's probably more difficult to figure out when a singular point is regular in the above sense.

Here's an example of an ODE with an irregular singular point at $z=0$, where the solution has a non-terminating Laurent series: $z^2 \frac{du}{dz}=u$, $u(z) = C \exp(-1/z)$.